# Angular jsonp SyntaxError

Tags: angularjs

I had everything working correctly using angular and now my whole app has broken.

I am getting SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Again it was working correctly and all of a sudden I get the SyntaxtError.

I have called a different endpoint on the same service using the same code below and this works correctly. When I see the error, the call is made but it is in their response. Could their endpoint throwing this?

```
 factory.eanApiRequest = function(url,params){

        return $http.jsonp(url, {params:params})
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
        });
    };
```

Comment: is this error in `response.data`? Printed with console.log?

Comment: how your url looks like?

Comment: my url is http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list? if I change it to info? it works

Comment: I remove console.log(response.data); and still get error